# How to set up a shared drive for Windows, Ubuntu, and OS X?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a 13" Macbook Air 6,2, and I finally have it set up to triple boot Ubuntu 13.10, Mac OS X 10.9.1, and Windows 8. However, I'd like a shared partition that I can drop files on between the three systems.

I've used Disk Utility from Mac OS to set up a partition for this, but Windows 8 is unable to see/use the partition (tried FAT, Mac OS Extended, and ExFAT formats).

My partition setup, if it matters, is:

- `/dev/sda1` - EFI partition
- `/dev/sda2` - Mac OS X
- `/dev/sda3` - Mac Recovery HD
- `/dev/sda4` - Windows 8 (NTFS)
- `/dev/sda5` - Ubuntu (Ext4)
- `/dev/sda6` - Linux swap
- `/dev/sda7` - Shared partition

How can I use Disk Utility (or something else) to modify my partition to be accessible by Ubuntu, Windows, *and* Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

The original FAT16 has a 2gb size limit.  FAT32 might work.(4gb per file max)
You should be able to mount a NTFS file system under linux although the write function is considered experimental.

For some versions of MAC it is necessary to buy a software driver to support read and write for the NTFS file system.

The original msdos specification allowed for 4 primary partitions.  If you wanted more than 4 one of the 4 slots had to be an **extended partition** type and the **extended partition** could then contain a number of partitions.

If the MAC disk utility violated this by allowing more than 4 partition without an extended partition this could be causing the problem.

Comment: I'm not super concerned about file size limits right now, but the FAT drive (nor either of the other formats I mentioned) doesn't even show up in Windows Explorer to have files added to it.

Comment: Does it show up under **Disk Management**?  Maybe you just have to assign it a drive letter.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The first four partitions show up, but the remainder (Ubuntu, swap, and shared) just shows up as a block of unallocated space.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to swap partition sda3 for sda7.  I realize this is NOT easy, but it is easier than creating an extended partition if you don't already have one.